# Multiple groups as super user on HDFS- Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Trying to give more than one group as SuperUser group for HDFS from Cloudera

Superuser Group
dfs.permissions.supergroup, dfs.permissions.superusergroup
:
GroupA,GroupB

But in Environment_1 only GroupA has superuser access
in Environment_2 no group has superuser access

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't add two groups for super user. As an alternative, you can add all the users to another group and configure to dfs.permissions.supergroup, dfs.permissions.superusergroup.